# How to uninstall tomcat completely (including server connection) in ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I installed tomcat in root directory following a tutorial. It was successfull and I could connect tomcat as local host. Later I had to change the directory. So I deleted the files from the /opt directory(where I installed earlier). Later I installed tomcat in another directory. But when i try to connect, it looks for the startup.sh file in the old directory which is not there now. As a result I'm unable to connect to tomcat server.
Is there any solution for this problem?

I tried to set the CATALINA path to my current startup.sh path, but still could'nt connect

Answer (score 5):

Follow this on the command line

```
sudo apt remove --purge tomcat8 tomcat8-docs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Use the above to purge any app from your system including config files.

Once this is complete you can use something like find or locate to remove any remaining stragglers.

```
sudo apt install locate && sudo updatedb
locate tomcat
```

And you can manually delete anything that might remain.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer to "How to uninstall *packagename* completely in [Debian-based distro X]".